# Matlab AppDesigner: Listbox from Excel

Tags: excel, matlab, listbox

I'm creating an app in App Designer. What I would like to do is when selecting one or multiple options, these get assigned a value of 1.

The list(i.e. "Column") is read in the following way and list options are assigned to a struct variable with a default value of 0.

```
table1 = readtable("file.xls");

for i = 1:length(rmmissing(table1{:,"Column"}))
    s.(char(rmmissing(table1{i,"Column"}))) = 0;
end
```

This outputs the following table.

```
s.Anna = 0 
s.Bett = 0
s.Cyrielle = 0
s.Dylan = 0
```

My problem is that I can't figure out a way of updating the value from 0 to 1, whenever I highlight one of the options. I don't know how to essentially pick up a selected value and updating it.

So as an example, If I highlight "Anna" and "Cyrielle", these should update to 1, as shown below.

```
s.Anna = 1
s.Bett = 0
s.Cyrielle = 1
s.Dylan = 0
```

I tried an if statement like. Whilst this works, it means I have to hard-code the names, which I don't want. So it needs to dynamically pick out the name that is selected.

```
    if app.ColumnListBox.Value == "Anna"
        s.Anna = 1;
    else
        s.Anna = 0;
    end
```

The listbox would look like this:
[Listbox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t42bZ.png)

The output I get when selecting one name is:

```
s = 

  struct with fields:

        Anna: 1
        Bett: 0
    Cyrielle: 0
       Dylan: 0
```

However if I select multiple options, everything goes to 0:
[Multiple names](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Sehy.png)

```
s = 

  struct with fields:

        Anna: 0
        Bett: 0
    Cyrielle: 0
       Dylan: 0
```

The code now is as follows:

```
names = fieldnames(s);
for j = 1:numel(names)
    name = names{j};
    if app.ListBox.Value == string(name)
            s.(name) = 1;
        else
            s.(name) = 0;
    end
end

assignin("base","s",s)
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: What have you tried? What's your specific issue? Have you seen the `assignin` function documentation? Assigning loose variables to your workspace is bad practise as you have little control about overwriting or name-safety, a better plan would be to assign them to a struct with named fields.

Comment: @Wolfie, I updated the post. Hope it's a bit more clear now.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to make your `if` condition less hard coded with something like

```
names = fieldnames(s);
for iField = 1:numel(names)
    % Assign current name to variable, e.g. "Anna"
    name = names{iField};
    % loop over the fields and check if selected
    if app.ColumnListBox.Value == string(name)
        s.(name) = 1;
    else
        s.(name) = 0;
    end
```

Comment: Thanks Wolfie. This works, however only if I highlight one option. As soon as I highlight multiple, it sets it back to default value.

Comment: Can you edit your question to include more details about what the listbox `value` is if you select more than one? A cell array you could also loop over or use `ismember` with instead of `==`?

Comment: More info added